# Изменить курсор на свой C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите как изменить курсор на свой? Делаю так :

```
 Cursor cur = new Cursor(new System.IO.MemoryStream(global::MSU.Properties.Resources.cursorDragDrop));
```

Пишет ошибку -

> Наиболее подходящий перегруженный метод для "System.IO.MemoryStream.MemoryStream(int)" имеет несколько недопустимых аргументов

Answer (score 6, accepted):

К примеру можно сделать так (из доступных курсоров):

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

Или же свой курсор вот так:

```
Cursor.Current = new Cursor("C:\\<путь к файлу>\\icon.cur");
```

Кстати, обратите внимание на расширение файла `.cur`, к примеру `.gif` туда нельзя упаковать. В `VisualStudio` есть возможность создать `Cursor File` (по крайней мере была). Все что Вам нужно - это указать путь к файлу и собственно говоря - сам файл. Будет полезно: [Cursors - свойства](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kyzy9zck.aspx)

---

Если хочется зашить в программу, то думаю стоит добавить файл курсора(`.cur`) в ресурсы проекта. Затем в коде получить этот файл, конвертировать и создать курсор, что-то на подобии этого:

```
var img = new Bitmap(WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.myCursor);
Icon icon = Icon.FromHandle(img.GetHicon());
Cursor cur = new Cursor(icon.Handle);
Cursor.Current = cur;
```

Данный код приведен в качестве альтернативного примера, но в нем имеются свои недостатки в виде утечки нативных ресурсов. Также, если  кликнуть мышкой в окне чужой программы - может возникнуть проблема. Поэтому советую ознакомиться с этим ответом [Change Cursor HotSpot in WinForms .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/550965/5275890), он будет более правильным, с использованием `WinAPI`.

Comment: А нельзя как то зашить в программу?

Comment: @Winteriscoming, думаю, что Вы спокойно можете добавить файл в проект и оттуда его брать, никто ведь не запрещает.

Comment: @Winteriscoming, посмотрите дополнение ответа

Comment: Второй вариант работает!

Comment: `Icon.FromHandle(img.GetHicon())` - если не ошибаюсь, где-то в этом районе проблема с утечкой нативных ресурсов.

Comment: @Qwertiy, имеется такое. Для иллюстрации самой идеи и примера - вполне достаточно. Тем более я прикрепил ссылку на рабочий вариант.

Comment: Думаю, стоит всё же про это написать в ответе.

Comment: @Qwertiy, дополнил ответ. Спасибо за подсказку.