# Как изменить курсор в приложении .NET Framework Windows Forms? C++

Tags: .net, winforms, c++-cli

Я хочу, чтобы в окне программы изменялся курсор на курсор из файла .cur, который я выберу. Как можно это сделать? В Windows Forms только начинаю разбираться
Язык - c++
Upd: Курсор свой добавил, но цвет у него, почему-то, чисто чёрный, вне зависимости от курсора.

`this->Cursor = gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Cursor("resources\\aero_arrow.cur");`

Comment: 1 ответ из гугла: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/566299/Изменить-курсор-на-свой-c-winforms

Comment: Извините, я пишу на с++, а по ссылке, которую Вы скинули - С#

Comment: Windows Forms не поддерживает разработку из-под С++, только C++CLI,

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо